# Vaadin 7 - NoClassDefFoundError with fresh project using Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, noclassdeffounderror, vaadin7

I installed the Vaadin plugin through Eclipse and created a new Vaadin 7 project, deploying locally onto Tomcat 8.

On trying to run the boilerplate application that Vaadin provides, however, I get the following NoClassDefFoundError exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/shared/Connector
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2495)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
```

I tracked the Connector class down to be in my Java Resources/Ivy/vaadin-shared-7.5.4.jar, which is on my Build Path.

Has anyone any experience on fixing this?

I also had to manually download and add a JSoup.jar as Vaadin complained it was missing on creating a new Vaadin 7 project.  I'm wondering if this is a known issue....

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run maven install and paste the output?